# select where x in y with varying lengths

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry, poorly descripted title and couldn't think of how to phrase it.

Working on a system which has tiered-view permissions. To better describe what I mean...

```
         0th tier
        /   \
     3         5
   /   \      /   \
 3004 3005  5004  5008
  /
 3004001
```

A users nodes (they can belong to multiple) is assigned via a table structured as

```
ID | Node
---------
20 | 3004
```

A user can belong to multiple tiers. Working on the security section - someone who belongs to 3004 should be able to edit someone who belongs to 3004001.

I'm not sure how to handle comparing the varying length tiers to see who a user should be able to edit. Specific example: user belongs to 3004 as well as 5. How do I get all IDs below 3004 as well as below 5?

Is there a clean, reusable way to do this? Not looking for spoon fed code, a push in the right direction of what to research would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark, that is not really relevant, it's using a different method to store hierarchical data.

Comment: @RedFilter: That'll teach me to read the question properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed that node is a `varchar` or similar. If it is an `int`, you'll need to do some casting to use the approach below. It wasn't clear to me whether `ID` in your table was the `UserID` or not, so I hard-coded the `WHERE` criteria:

```
select n2.*
from MyTable n1
inner join MyTable n2 on n2.Node like n1.Node + '%'
where n1.Node in ('5', '3004')
```

If `ID` is in fact `UserID`, you can do:

```
select n2.*
from MyTable n1
inner join MyTable n2 on n2.Node like n1.Node + '%'
where n1.ID = @UserID
```

Comment: You ever have one of those duh moments? Thanks, I'll mark as answer once the timer lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the LIKE comparison in your WHERE clause.

```
SELECT [ID] FROM Table WHERE [Node] LIKE '5_%' OR [Node] LIKE '3004_%'
```

The _% is similar to saying "starts with but is not equal to". So it will not match '5' or '3004' in the example above but will match '50' or '3004001'